# Where the constructor method is called on react native?

Tags: react-native

My react-native app use the pure react-native, it doesn´t use expo for example or a some type of tool, see:

```
const App: () => React$Node = () => {
  
  return (
    <>
      <View style={styles.sectionBody}>
        <Text style={styles.textTeste}>Teste</Text>
        <ActivityIndicator />
        <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#000000"/>
      </View>
    </>
  );
};
```

I want to use the next constructor method on my application, where do i put it?, see:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  
    this.state = {
      isLoading: true,
      dataSource: null,
    };
  }
```

Comment: Functional components do not have constructors. You can use a `useEffect` hook without any dependencies to mimic "component did mount" behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`You are using a functional component, A constructor can only be used inside a class component,`

For using constructor convert your functional component into a class component, but anything that you wanted to do in the class component is now supported in functional component too.

Comment: Ah i get it, tks!

Comment: glad that it helps you, You can accept my answer if there isn't any confusion yet.